# Conditional Expectation of Form $E[g(X,Y)|Y=y]$

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables and $g$ is a linear combination of them. I am confused about the applicability of the two approaches I met to compute $E[g(X,Y)|Y=y]$. The first is to make use of $f_{X|Y}$ (the conditional pdf), and the second is to directly compute $E[g(X,y)]$.

Could anyone explain when can I use the first method and when can I use the second? My current thought is that we can always use the first one but can only use the second one if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Is that correct? How to verify that if so?

Any answers or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The second approach you speak of is in fact, the same as the first approach since in the independence case, $f_{X\mid Y} = f_X$

Comment: $E[g(X,Y)|Y=y]=E[g(X,y)|Y=y]$. You cannot omit the conditioning on the right hand side unless $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Both comments make sense to me. Thank you.